# Objective C two equal strings are not evaluating to equal even when the bytes are the same

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I have a `product` string:

```
NSString* product = models[[[peripheral identifier] UUIDString]];
```

and in the debugger I can print:

```
po product
>>> X3
```

and I can check the bytes:

```
po [product dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
>>> <5833>
```

I can also check the bytes of the literal string `@"X3"`:

```
po [@"X3" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
>>> <5833>
```

And I get the same output.
However, when I try to do:

```
[product isEqualToString:@"X3"]
>>> <nil>
```

I get `nil`. What the heck!? I can understand when there is a hidden character or something, but when the bytes evaluate to the same thing, then I'm baffled.

I can even do:

```
NSData *d = [product dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *d2 = [@"X3" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
po [d isEqualToData:d2]
>>> YES
```

Comment: What do you get if you use `NSUTF16StringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`? I'm wondering if there's a BOM involved.

Comment: Interesting. Actually, you should get a bool, not nil https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407803-isequaltostring?language=objc

Comment: The logical conclusion is that the literal @"X3" is being internally represented in a manner different than the product NSString. So the code works when you specify an encoding and fails otherwise when using the default

Comment: Must be a default setting on XCode somewhere

Comment: @SergioFlores Usually, using po (print object), when it's a Boolean value (primitive value), with is 0, is (often ? always ?) interpreted as 0x0000... so nil. That's normal behavior in debugguer. For your issue, I'd say that `UUIDString` doesn't use UTF8 so it it may think they are different. Cf. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507991/isequaltostring-always-returns-false But clearly, that's strange behavior.

Comment: What happens if you do the reverse: `[NSUUID initWithUUIDString:@"X3"] isEqual:models[[peripheral identifier]]]`?